# A .ps file won't open in any software I've tried - what may be wrong with the file syntax?

Tags: adobe, preview, postscript

I have a postscript file that won't open in Adobe or Preview. This .ps file is the output of the following:

1. Draw a knot (for example 5-1) in a software called "Knotscape".
2. Save the drawing as a postscript file.

I'm guessing there is a syntax problem in my ps file that recent versions of Adobe or Prview won't accept anymore. If someone could help pointing out where that problem is and perhaps how to correct it, I'd be so grateful.

Here is the code of this .ps file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: Tk Canvas Widget
%%For: Van Pham
%%Title: Window .drawing0.c
%%CreationDate: Wed Jan  8 14:05:32 2020
%%BoundingBox: 306 396 308 398
%%Pages: 1
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%EndComments

%%BeginProlog
/CurrentEncoding [
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/exclam/quotedbl/numbersign/dollar/percent/ampersand/quotesingle
/parenleft/parenright/asterisk/plus/comma/hyphen/period/slash
/zero/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven
/eight/nine/colon/semicolon/less/equal/greater/question
/at/A/B/C/D/E/F/G
/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O
/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W
/X/Y/Z/bracketleft/backslash/bracketright/asciicircum/underscore
/grave/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o
/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w
/x/y/z/braceleft/bar/braceright/asciitilde/space
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/space/space/space/space/space/space/space
/space/exclamdown/cent/sterling/currency/yen/brokenbar/section
/dieresis/copyright/ordfeminine/guillemotleft/logicalnot/hyphen/registered/macron
/degree/plusminus/twosuperior/threesuperior/acute/mu/paragraph/periodcentered
/cedilla/onesuperior/ordmasculine/guillemotright/onequarter/onehalf/threequarters/questiondown
/Agrave/Aacute/Acircumflex/Atilde/Adieresis/Aring/AE/Ccedilla
/Egrave/Eacute/Ecircumflex/Edieresis/Igrave/Iacute/Icircumflex/Idieresis
/Eth/Ntilde/Ograve/Oacute/Ocircumflex/Otilde/Odieresis/multiply
/Oslash/Ugrave/Uacute/Ucircumflex/Udieresis/Yacute/Thorn/germandbls
/agrave/aacute/acircumflex/atilde/adieresis/aring/ae/ccedilla
/egrave/eacute/ecircumflex/edieresis/igrave/iacute/icircumflex/idieresis
/eth/ntilde/ograve/oacute/ocircumflex/otilde/odieresis/divide
/oslash/ugrave/uacute/ucircumflex/udieresis/yacute/thorn/ydieresis
] def

50 dict begin
% This is a standard prolog for Postscript generated by Tk's canvas
% widget.
% RCS: @(#) $Id$

% The definitions below just define all of the variables used in
% any of the procedures here.  This is needed for obscure reasons
% explained on p. 716 of the Postscript manual (Section H.2.7,
% "Initializing Variables," in the section on Encapsulated Postscript).

/baseline 0 def
/stipimage 0 def
/height 0 def
/justify 0 def
/lineLength 0 def
/spacing 0 def
/stipple 0 def
/strings 0 def
/xoffset 0 def
/yoffset 0 def
/tmpstip null def


/cstringshow {
    {
    dup type /stringtype eq
    { show } { glyphshow }
    ifelse
    }
    forall
} bind def



/cstringwidth {
    0 exch 0 exch
    {
    dup type /stringtype eq
    { stringwidth } { 
        currentfont /Encoding get exch 1 exch put (\001) stringwidth 
        }
    ifelse 
    exch 3 1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    }
    forall
} bind def

% font ISOEncode font
% This procedure changes the encoding of a font from the default
% Postscript encoding to current system encoding.  It's typically invoked just
% before invoking "setfont".  The body of this procedure comes from
% Section 5.6.1 of the Postscript book.

/ISOEncode {
    dup length dict begin
    {1 index /FID ne {def} {pop pop} ifelse} forall
    /Encoding CurrentEncoding def
    currentdict
    end

    % I'm not sure why it's necessary to use "definefont" on this new
    % font, but it seems to be important; just use the name "Temporary"
    % for the font.

    /Temporary exch definefont
} bind def

% StrokeClip
%
% This procedure converts the current path into a clip area under
% the assumption of stroking.  It's a bit tricky because some Postscript
% interpreters get errors during strokepath for dashed lines.  If
% this happens then turn off dashes and try again.

/StrokeClip {
    {strokepath} stopped {
    (This Postscript printer gets limitcheck overflows when) =
    (stippling dashed lines;  lines will be printed solid instead.) =
    [] 0 setdash strokepath} if
    clip
} bind def

% desiredSize EvenPixels closestSize
%
% The procedure below is used for stippling.  Given the optimal size
% of a dot in a stipple pattern in the current user coordinate system,
% compute the closest size that is an exact multiple of the device's
% pixel size.  This allows stipple patterns to be displayed without
% aliasing effects.

/EvenPixels {
    % Compute exact number of device pixels per stipple dot.
    dup 0 matrix currentmatrix dtransform
    dup mul exch dup mul add sqrt

    % Round to an integer, make sure the number is at least 1, and compute
    % user coord distance corresponding to this.
    dup round dup 1 lt {pop 1} if
    exch div mul
} bind def

% width height string StippleFill --
%
% Given a path already set up and a clipping region generated from
% it, this procedure will fill the clipping region with a stipple
% pattern.  "String" contains a proper image description of the
% stipple pattern and "width" and "height" give its dimensions.  Each
% stipple dot is assumed to be about one unit across in the current
% user coordinate system.  This procedure trashes the graphics state.

/StippleFill {
    % The following code is needed to work around a NeWSprint bug.

    /tmpstip 1 index def

    % Change the scaling so that one user unit in user coordinates
    % corresponds to the size of one stipple dot.
    1 EvenPixels dup scale

    % Compute the bounding box occupied by the path (which is now
    % the clipping region), and round the lower coordinates down
    % to the nearest starting point for the stipple pattern.  Be
    % careful about negative numbers, since the rounding works
    % differently on them.

    pathbbox
    4 2 roll
    5 index div dup 0 lt {1 sub} if cvi 5 index mul 4 1 roll
    6 index div dup 0 lt {1 sub} if cvi 6 index mul 3 2 roll

    % Stack now: width height string y1 y2 x1 x2
    % Below is a doubly-nested for loop to iterate across this area
    % in units of the stipple pattern size, going up columns then
    % across rows, blasting out a stipple-pattern-sized rectangle at
    % each position

    6 index exch {
    2 index 5 index 3 index {
        % Stack now: width height string y1 y2 x y

        gsave
        1 index exch translate
        5 index 5 index true matrix tmpstip imagemask
        grestore
    } for
    pop
    } for
    pop pop pop pop pop
} bind def

% -- AdjustColor --
% Given a color value already set for output by the caller, adjusts
% that value to a grayscale or mono value if requested by the CL
% variable.

/AdjustColor {
    CL 2 lt {
    currentgray
    CL 0 eq {
        .5 lt {0} {1} ifelse
    } if
    setgray
    } if
} bind def

% x y strings spacing xoffset yoffset justify stipple DrawText --
% This procedure does all of the real work of drawing text.  The
% color and font must already have been set by the caller, and the
% following arguments must be on the stack:
%
% x, y -    Coordinates at which to draw text.
% strings - An array of strings, one for each line of the text item,
%       in order from top to bottom.
% spacing - Spacing between lines.
% xoffset - Horizontal offset for text bbox relative to x and y: 0 for
%       nw/w/sw anchor, -0.5 for n/center/s, and -1.0 for ne/e/se.
% yoffset - Vertical offset for text bbox relative to x and y: 0 for
%       nw/n/ne anchor, +0.5 for w/center/e, and +1.0 for sw/s/se.
% justify - 0 for left justification, 0.5 for center, 1 for right justify.
% stipple - Boolean value indicating whether or not text is to be
%       drawn in stippled fashion.  If text is stippled,
%       procedure StippleText must have been defined to call
%       StippleFill in the right way.
%
% Also, when this procedure is invoked, the color and font must already
% have been set for the text.

/DrawText {
    /stipple exch def
    /justify exch def
    /yoffset exch def
    /xoffset exch def
    /spacing exch def
    /strings exch def

    % First scan through all of the text to find the widest line.

    /lineLength 0 def
    strings {
    cstringwidth pop
    dup lineLength gt {/lineLength exch def} {pop} ifelse
    newpath
    } forall

    % Compute the baseline offset and the actual font height.

    0 0 moveto (TXygqPZ) false charpath
    pathbbox dup /baseline exch def
    exch pop exch sub /height exch def pop
    newpath

    % Translate coordinates first so that the origin is at the upper-left
    % corner of the text's bounding box. Remember that x and y for
    % positioning are still on the stack.

    translate
    lineLength xoffset mul
    strings length 1 sub spacing mul height add yoffset mul translate

    % Now use the baseline and justification information to translate so
    % that the origin is at the baseline and positioning point for the
    % first line of text.

    justify lineLength mul baseline neg translate

    % Iterate over each of the lines to output it.  For each line,
    % compute its width again so it can be properly justified, then
    % display it.

    strings {
    dup cstringwidth pop
    justify neg mul 0 moveto
    stipple {


        % The text is stippled, so turn it into a path and print
        % by calling StippledText, which in turn calls StippleFill.
        % Unfortunately, many Postscript interpreters will get
        % overflow errors if we try to do the whole string at
        % once, so do it a character at a time.

        gsave
        /char (X) def
        {
        dup type /stringtype eq {
            % This segment is a string.
            {
                char 0 3 -1 roll put
                currentpoint
                gsave
                char true charpath clip StippleText
                grestore
                char stringwidth translate
                moveto
            } forall
        } {
            % This segment is glyph name
            % Temporary override
            currentfont /Encoding get exch 1 exch put
            currentpoint
            gsave (\001) true charpath clip StippleText
            grestore
                (\001) stringwidth translate
            moveto
        } ifelse
        } forall
        grestore 
    } {cstringshow} ifelse
    0 spacing neg translate
    } forall
} bind def

%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
/CL 2 def
%%EndSetup

%%Page: 1 1
save
306.0 396.0 translate
1.001 1.001 scale
0 0 translate
0 1 moveto 1 1 lineto 1 0 lineto 0 0 lineto closepath clip newpath
restore showpage

%%Trailer
end
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PostScript program claims to be EPS compliant:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
```

but does not include an %%BoundingBox comment, which is not legal for EPS and will seriously confuse any interpreter which tries to treat it as an EPS.

The portion of the program which actually executes anything (as opposed to defining functionality) is this:

```
save
306.0 396.0 translate
1.001 1.001 scale
0 0 translate
0 1 moveto 1 1 lineto 1 0 lineto 0 0 lineto closepath clip newpath
restore showpage
```

So that saves the current state, moves the origin (0,0) from the bottom left of the media to 306, 306. All subsequent co-ordinate operations will therefore start at that location on the media. It scales the CTM by almost exactly 1. Translates the origin again, but this time to 0,0 so it has no effect (no it doesn't move it **back** to the bottom left, these operations are cumulative).

It then creates a path 1 unit square, and makes that a clip region. All subsequent drawing operations which lie outside that region will be clipped out, not drawn.

It then restores the state back to the state at the start of the program.

Finally it renders the page content.

As you may have noticed, it doesn't actually draw anything at all. So there's nothing wrong with the program, it's merely pointless :-)

You need to go back to the authors of the program and find out from them why it emits PostScript that doesn't draw anything.